# How can I use a 12v output to trigger IFTTT?

Tags: smart-home, ifttt

I have a house alarm which will apply 12v to an output when an intrusion is detected.  I'm looking for a simple device that will take this 12v as an input to trigger an event which I can then use IFTTT to do something else, such as turn on my Philips Hue lights for example.  Has anyone any experience of devices that can take a 12v input as a trigger and then fire an event to IFTTT?  I'd appreciate any recommendations or guidance on implementing something like this.

Comment: use the output to energize a relay ... then your question becomes `how to trigger IFTTT with a switch?`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is 2 Resistors and then any microcontroller  with a 3.3v GPIO input pin (e.g. ESP8266)

You need to build a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider), the equations on that page will help you work out what the ratio of the 2 resistor values needs to be (But something like 20 kohm and 7.5 kohm should be in the right ball park).
You can also use this [calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/voltage-divider-calculator/) to do the maths for you.

When the pin goes high, you get that information with the microcontroller and then you can make a HTTP [request](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) to IFTTT that triggers your action.